# How to dynamically replace chars in a string with chars in another string having same structure based on condition?

Tags: python, string

I have a graph of dependencies where there's parent and child nodes. Child nodes have a **@** sign indicating that char/number is the **same as the parent node**. I understand the title might be weird, let me give you an example:

Initial reference variable:

```
ref = '12345.1.1'
```

Strings that will need replacing within:

```
example1 = '@.1.2'
example2 = '@.@.3'
```

Outcome after conversion/replacing (this is what I need help with):

```
# Make some magic, replace @'s with matching parent digits to get this output on string variables above:
example1 = '12345.1.2'
example2 = '12345.1.3'
```

In essence, **how do I replace the @ char (*if present*) to its matching "parent" stringified digits?** I guess it might be able to work using replace or regex, but if there's any builtin methods that would work, I'd be happy to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ref = '12345.1.1'
example1 = '@.1.2'
example2 = '@.@.3' 

def replace(text, ref='12345.1.1', split='.', placeholder='@'):
    ref = ref.split(split)
    text = text.split(split)
    return split.join(txt1 if txt2 == placeholder else txt2 
                      for txt1, txt2 in zip(ref, text))

print(replace(example1))
print(replace(example2))
print(replace('@.@.@'))
```

output

```
12345.1.2
12345.1.3
12345.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit cumbersome, but this should do it:

```
import re


class Replacement:

    def __init__(self, ref):
        self.ref = ref.split(".")
        self.counter = 0

    def repl(self, match):
        if match.group() == "@":
            res = self.ref[self.counter]
            self.counter += 1
            return res
        return match.group()


example1 = '@.1.2'
example2 = '@.@.3'

for example in [example1, example2]:
    r = Replacement(ref='12345.1.1')
    result = re.sub("@", r.repl, example)
    print(result)
```

**Output**

```
12345.1.2
12345.1.3
```

Note that you need to create a new `Replacement` object or restart the `counter` for each example in your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Concise function

```
def replace_char(string: str, palce_holder: str = '@', split: str = '.') -> str:
    return split.join((node[0] if node[1] == palce_holder else node[1] for node in zip(ref.split('.'), string.split('.'))))
```

Comment: `import this`. it's not always about one-liners.